# Zoom very much and keep a high quality of the image without loading a large image on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, image, zooming

Does anyone know about some framework or some tutorial to help me develop a feature into an iPhone app which will allow the user to zoom in very much on an image and display high-quality details of the image without loading the large image. Something like Google Maps.
You can see an example here: http://www.zoomify.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `CATiledLayer` documentation there should be two sample projects that can help you.

Comment: Thanks! I've found a nice example here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ScrollViewSuite/Introduction/Intro.html